# Laravel class@method

Tags: laravel

This is Laravel 5.4 and I'm new to the framework.

I'm trying to create a custom validator but I want to use my own class rather than having a load of logic in App\Providers

However, when I call the class like this: 'MultiDateFieldValidator@validate' I get an error: **Class MultiDateFieldValidator does not exist**

If I use the full namespace it works: 'App\Validators\MultiDateFieldValidator@validate'

So my question is whether its normal to have to use the full namespace in the class@method call? Or whether you have to do some Laravel magic to make it recognise the namespace at the top of the file?

Code is below.

Thanks!

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Validators\MultiDateFieldValidator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('foo', 'MultiDateFieldValidator@validate' );
```

}

Comment: try `use App\Validators\MultiDateFieldValidator as MultiDateFieldValidator`

Comment: Didn't work :/  There must be some Laravel Voodoo

Comment: what name space is MultiDateFieldValidator in? definitely namespace App\Validators; ? and try with a \ infront of  MultiDateFieldValidator

Comment: Leading slash didn't work. The namespace is definitely correct as I can new up MultiDateFieldValidator...

Comment: Seems normal to me.  The `use` is in the AppServiceProvider, but the class wouldn't be evaluated in AppServiceProvider because you're just passing a string.  Therefore Validator has no idea about that `use`.